# How to get the ref.current dom element when using react-select and react refs?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a group of react selects using the react-select package – https://react-select.com/home.

I have a component that wraps three react-selects – something basically like this:

```
   import Select from "react-select"

   function SelectGroup(){
     const ref1 = useRef(null);
     const ref2 = useRef(null);
     const ref3 = useRef(null);
   
     return (
       <div>
         <Select ref={ref1} />
         <Select ref={ref2} />
         <Select ref={ref3} />
       </div>
     )
   }
```

I need to perform some checks to see what's in focus. The reason I am doing this is because the group of selects is a single component that needs to be able to allow the user to navigate in multiple ways through the keyboard. Spacebar, and enter keys should allow the user to shift the focus to the next select element. Arrow keys should allow the user to go to the next or previous select. So, focus needs to be managed somehow, and this means knowing what's currently in focus.

Normally, I would do that like this:

```
  function isActiveElement(ref){
    return ref?.current === document.activeElement
  }
```

However, for ref.current react-select returns an object called StateManager – https://react-select.com/props#statemanager-props

So, `ref.current === document.activeElement` always returns false.

How, can I check to see which react-select is in focus? I was unable to find anything about this in the react-select docs. Maybe, I'm missing it? I have solved this problem others ways, but I was curious if there is a way to do it this "simpler way" I describe above, which may be the more common approach.

Comment: You can use `onFocus` prop. https://react-select.com/props

Comment: Thanks @YasinTazeoglu that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the `focus` and the `blur` event to keep track of the currently focused `Select`:

```
export default function App() {
  const [focus, setFocus] = useState(-1);
  const onBlur = () => setFocus(-1);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Current focus: {focus}</div>
      <Select
        onFocus={() => setFocus(0)}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        options={colourOptions}
      />
      <Select
        onFocus={() => setFocus(1)}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        options={colourOptions}
      />
      <Select
        onFocus={() => setFocus(2)}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        options={colourOptions}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67340978/how-to-get-the-ref-current-dom-element-when-using-react-select-and-react-refs]

Comment: thanks! This works. @NearHuscarl Your advice helped me take a very similar approach.